# Why curl fails to establish a connection but openssl succeeds

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

When I run the below command from my box -

```
$ openssl s_client -connect **xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx** -tls1

Please note that when I use the command like below :

$ openssl s_client -connect **https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx** -tls1 

I get below error:

getservbyname failure for //xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
usage: s_client args
```

I get connected to the xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx and below is the output [an extract]:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3445 bytes and written 423 bytes
...........
```

But when I try the same via curl it fails with below error:

```
$curl -v -1 https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx

* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

How can I connect to the same box port without any issues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Skip the certificate](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) check with CURL

```
$curl -v -k -1 https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
```

Or get the respective certificate and [add it to curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).

Comment: I use the command as mentioned in the link mentioned by you and get all the certs starting with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and ending with -----END CERTIFICATE------- - I copied and pasted it in a say cert.cert file. Now how can I use this cert in curl to establish connection

Comment: When I try the below command I get issue if trying with openssl:  openssl s_client -connect xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx  -cert ./cert.cert -tls1
unable to load client certificate private key file
140184327177888:error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line:pem_lib.c:795:

Comment: in curl you use --cacert `file`  is all in there

Comment: I get the below output: ~$ curl -v --cacert cert.cert https://www.xxxxx.com:xxxxx
* About to connect() to www.xxxxx.com port xxxxx (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx... connected
* error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: cert.cert
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

* Closing connection #0
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: cert.cert
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

Comment: There is a CURL_CA_BUNDLE  option you can specify the cert location,read the manual

Comment: I did that export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/home/myname" and ran the above command but still get the same result . I am running it on Red HAT Linux

Comment: @Prakash http://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help - it resolves my issue